# Using Leaflet Search Plugin to Search Shapefile

Tags: html, github, search, leaflet, shapefile

I have a [map](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-morning-0816u?file=/index.html) that I built in CodeSandbox that loads and displays a few shapefiles. I would like to add a search bar to this map so that the names of the shapefiles are searchable. From what I gather my best option is to use the Leaflet search plugin (https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) to achieve the same affect as something like this: https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/geojson-layer.html.

I'm not sure how exactly to implement the plugin code to my map to make the TestShapefile searchable. In particular, I'm uncertain how to load the .css and .js files from the github website and if this plugin will actually work with a shapefile as opposed to a GeoJSON. Any help putting this together would be greatly appreciated.